# What is the most efficient way to convert shaking/vibration to electrivity?

Tags: electrical-engineering, electromagnetism, magnets

What is the most efficient way to get electricity from shaking? I am thinking about something like shown in the picture below (the magnet is going inside the coil), but maybe there is a better design for it. Efficient I mean by power, like what percentage of vibration energy is converted to electricity. If it is a coil, what would be the best coil design (how many turns of wire and wire diameter I need, etc.)? Maybe there are some articles about it and how to fully calculate it as well.

[image]

There is this flashlight design on the internet, but is it the most efficient?

[image]

Comment: It exists. I have a rechargeable torch that does exactly that except there is a spring at either end of the tube.

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, I saw it on the internet. The question is it the most efficient way or there are other ways to do it?

Comment: Yes, it is efficient / battery never goes glat and you can always recharge it.

Comment: worry a bit more about your diodes.  Shaking at some inconsistent frequency needs to get controlled lest you undo the work on the return stroke.